# Using the null conditional operator and actions

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Action SomeAction { get; set; }
}
```

Before [c#-6.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-6.0) when calling `SomeAction` because it has the potential to be `null` we would do something like:

```
var action = SomeAction;
if (action != null)
{
    action();
}
```

However, in [c#-6.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-6.0) we now have the null conditional operator and so can write the above as:

```
SomeAction?.Invoke();
```

However I find this slightly less readable because of the `Invoke` call. Is there anyway to use the null conditional operator in this circumstance without the `Invoke` call? Something like:

```
SomeAction?();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no such syntax in C# 6.0 or 7.0. [The null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) comes in two flavors:

- null-condition member access `?.`, which you already rejected as too verbose
- null-condition index `?[`, which doesn't make sense for delegates (and can't be added as an extension, or anything like that)

The documentation even directly mentions this:

> You need to explicitly call the `Invoke` method because there is no null-conditional delegate invocation syntax `PropertyChanged?(e)`. There were too many ambiguous parsing situations to allow it.